# Disable SoftKeyboard in MultiLine EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to paste clipboard content in a disabled EditText with no softkeyboard popup,
 with  following code

```
clipboardBox.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

android EditText does not respect line feeds, i.e. doesnt show multiline content
and puts it in single line.

I want to disable softkeyboard from popping up in a multiline content holder disabled EditText

Comment: ahhh.. foolish of me.. I achived this by making edittext editable false android:editable="false" did the trcik.

Comment: nope, not foolish of you! since in new APIs there is not editable flag!