# Android: Disable SoftKeyboard in MultiLine EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

Need some help to enable multiple lines in EditText **WITHOUT permiting softkeyboard to open**.

I DON'T use android's native softkeyboard. I have my own "softkeyboard" as a view inside activity.

I've tried these solutions, but they DID NOT WORK:

- [Disable SoftKeyboard in MultiLine EditText android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225027/disable-softkeyboard-in-multiline-edittext-android)
- [how to block virtual keyboard while clicking on edittext in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845285/how-to-block-virtual-keyboard-while-clicking-on-edittext-in-android)
- [(Similar) EditText with textPassword inputType, but without Softkeyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573614/edittext-with-textpassword-inputtype-but-without-softkeyboard)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine for Android 2 but doesn't work for SOME Android 4 phones (And I don't really know why):

```
<EditTextExtension
a:editable="false"
a:singleLine="false"/>
```

Class EdiTextExtension should override onCheckIsTextEditor() method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 ) {
        // resulting false for Android >= 11 will hide cursor
        // NOTE: this code works fine only with SOME devices and not all (WHY?)
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```